# Change "Shipping" label in Woocommerce email table totals?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am customizing the order email template in WooCommerce and need to change the title of "Shipping" to "Delivery," as well as change "Shipping address" to "Delivery address". I tried a plugin, "Say What" that would change the text but it did not work. There is a loop that handles all of this information.

[Woocommerce email template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEKl7.png)

This is the code on line 52 in the "email-order-details.php" page.

```
if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                    $i++;
                    if($total['label'] === "Shipping"){
                        //make second-last above total somehow
                    }
                    else{
                        ?><tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="3" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:left; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>" colspan="1"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                        </tr><?php
                    }
                }
            }
```

I assume this is a filter hook, but I am not sure how to use it.

```
woocommerce_get_order_item_totals
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using the following hooked function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'renaming_shipping_order_item_totals', 10, 3 );
function renaming_shipping_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    // Only on emails notifications
    if( ! is_wc_endpoint_url() )
        $total_rows['shipping']['label'] = __('Delivery', 'woocommerce');

    return $total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

To change the "Shipping address" label to "Delivery address" you need to copy/edit the template `email-addresses.php`, replacing:

```
_e( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' );
```

by:

```
_e( 'Delivery address', 'woocommerce' );
```

See: [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: Thank you!! that worked. How would I change the "Shipping address" label to "Delivery address". And one quick question, might be dumb, how did you figure out the name of the fields in the array.

Comment: that field is mentioned in line 42 in woocommerce/templates/emails/email-addresses.php 

    <h2><?php _e( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

Changing it gave me a fatal error though.