# How to change email labels in WooCommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is it possible to change email labels in WooCommerce - "Subtotal" and "Total" to sth else?

The email looks like [this on](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-css-woocommerce-emails/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50961499/11987538) to change the 'shipping' label, 
then you get it.

```php
function change_email_labels( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    // Only on emails notifications
    if( ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        $total_rows['cart_subtotal']['label'] = __( 'My text 1', 'woocommerce');
        $total_rows['order_total']['label'] = __( 'My text 2', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $total_rows;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'change_email_labels', 10, 3 );
```